# Vue: Typed props interface with optional properties

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I made a method I want to be available on all my Vue instances, which I can call in case of an error and render a specific error component. Something like [vue-error-page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-error-page). I'm using typescript and now I want to make sure that the component is called with the right typed props, to get a compile time error if there is a typo in the passed props.

Currently I have this in a shims.d.ts file:

```
import Vue, {VueConstructor} from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $error (component:VueConstructor<Vue>, props:unknown) : void;
    }
}
```

Which allows me to call my plugin like so. The passed object matches the props definition of the ErrorPage component:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import ErrorPage from "./views/ErrorPage.vue";
export default Vue.extend({
  mounted() {
    this.$error(ErrorPage, { errorTitle: "Could not load the page" });
  }
});
```

While this is working, I want to get a compile-time error if the props don't match what the component expects.

So I thought I'd change the shims.d.ts like this:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $error<Props> (component:ExtendedVue<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, Props>, props:Props) : void;
    }
}
```

Now I get compile time errors when the props object doesn't match. However, I also get errors when I do not pass in optional properties. My ErrorPage component looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Error",
  props: {
    errorTitle: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: "Error"
    },
    errorDescription: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default:
        "Something went wrong."
    }
  }
});
```

If I do not pass errorDescription, I should not get an error. That is what I am trying to accomplish. I want to be able to do the following things:

```
// Should compile and does right now.
this.$error(ErrorPage, {errorTitle: "Oops", errorDescription: "Something went wrong" });

// Should compile and does not right now. Fails with error:
// Argument of type '{ errorTitle: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ errorTitle: string; errorDescription: string; }'.
// Property 'errorDescription' is missing in type '{ errorTitle: string; }' but required in type '{ errorTitle: string; errorDescription: string; }'."
this.$error(ErrorPage, {errorTitle: "Oops" });
```

## TL;DR Question:

How can I make my method call type safe with props as an argument, while being able to omit optional properties? I am able to change both the shims.d.ts and the ErrorPage component.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you flag it as not required, the typescript type is still `String` and as such you need to pass it when calling the method.

You may try this (I haven't tested if it works)

Declare a type that is nullable, using an alias

`type ErrorDescriptionType = String | undefined | null`

And then pass this as the type for `errorDescription`

```
errorDescription: {
  type: Object as () => ErrorDescriptionType,
}
```

Comment: It's a good suggestion. I still get the same error though, unfortunately.